# Return a user event function value as a string in Python before the code is compiled

Tags: python, pandas, function, class, tkinter

I have a drag and drop GUI function that displays the filename and gives the file pathway. I am trying to plug that file path into Pandas to manipulate later down the road. My issue is that python trys to open the path way before the user can drop the file into the function. How do I tell it to wait until the user enters the data before it compiles. Below is the code that I am using and have narrowed it down to what I think is the problem. Bonus points if you can tell me how to turn the function into a class so that I dont have to edit the function per entry box.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import docx
import os
import zipfile
import re
import PyPDF2
from docx2pdf import convert
import csv
from math import *
from pathlib import Path
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress, stats
from tkinter import *
from tkinterdnd2 import *
from docx2pdf import convert

    

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.title('Pathfinder')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.config(bg='#039dfc')

 

def drop(event):
    var.set(event.data)
    stringvar = str(event.data) 
    size = len(stringvar)
    res = []  # list of file paths
    name = ""
    idx = 0
    while idx < size:
        if stringvar[idx] == "{":
            j = idx + 1
            while stringvar[j] != "}":
                name += stringvar[j]
                j += 1
            res.append(name)
            name = ""
            idx = j
        elif stringvar[idx] == " " and name != "":
            res.append(name)
            name = ""
        elif stringvar[idx] != " ":
            name += stringvar[idx]
        idx += 1
    if name != "":
        res.append(name)
    file_paths = res
    current_e_box_item = set(e_box.get())
    for file_path in file_paths:
        if file_path.endswith(".XLS"):
            path_object = Path(file_path)
            file_name = path_object.name
            if file_name not in current_e_box_item:
                e_box.insert("end", file_name)
                e_box.delete(0,last=size)
    print(file_name)
    print (res)
    print(file_path)
    print(path_object)
    print(stringvar)
    return file_path # this is what i want


var = StringVar()
e_box = Entry(root, textvar=var)
e_box.place(x=150, y=90, width=180, height=25)
e_box.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e_box.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)


File_as_DF = pd.read_excel(file_path) # This is where it needs to go


def drop2(event):
    var2.set(event.data)
    stringvar2 = str(event.data) 
    print (stringvar2) 
    
var2 = StringVar()
e_box2 = Entry(root, textvar=var2)
e_box2.place(x=150, y=150, width=180, height=25)
e_box2.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e_box2.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop2)


def drop3(event):
    var3.set(event.data)
    stringvar3 = str(event.data)
    print(stringvar3)

var3 = StringVar()
e_box3 = Entry(root, textvar=var3)
e_box3.place(x=150, y=200, width=180, height=25)
e_box3.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e_box3.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop3)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Delete the `File_as_DF = pd.read_excel(file_path)` line.  You're not doing anything with that `File_as_DF ` value anyway.  When you build out the rest of your program, you'll want whatever you were going to do with that to be kicked off from the `drop()` event.

Comment: Do we really need all of those imports to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Bryan Oakley, your comment is not the answer, nor was it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the main question -- you need this:

```
File_as_DF = pd.read_excel(file_path) # This is where it needs to go
```

to happen after your `drop()`, not before it.  Presumably you have a plan for what you want to do with that dataframe -- your `drop()` function should kick off a function that does that thing.

For the bonus points, instead of classes, I'd just have a function that builds a box along with its own drop function:

```
def drop2(event):
    var2.set(event.data)
    stringvar2 = str(event.data) 
    print (stringvar2) 
    
var2 = StringVar()
e_box2 = Entry(root, textvar=var2)
e_box2.place(x=150, y=150, width=180, height=25)
e_box2.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e_box2.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop2)


def drop3(event):
    var3.set(event.data)
    stringvar3 = str(event.data)
    print(stringvar3)

var3 = StringVar()
e_box3 = Entry(root, textvar=var3)
e_box3.place(x=150, y=200, width=180, height=25)
e_box3.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e_box3.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop3)
```

becomes:

```
def make_e_box():
    var = StringVar()
    def drop(event):
        var.set(event.data)
        print(event.data)
    e_box = Entry(root, textvar=var)
    e_box.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
    e_box.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)
    return e_box

make_e_box().place(x=150, y=150, width=180, height=25)
make_e_box().place(x=150, y=200, width=180, height=25)
```

Comment: I appreciate the make_e_box help. I will still need to get info returned from the 3 functions.

Comment: oh oh oh , i can make this work. Thank you Samwise.